# UIViewController subclass subclass - how do I avoid super's implementation?

Tags: cocoa, uiviewcontroller, subclass

Here's my situation: Subclass B inherits from Subclass A inherits from UIViewController. In Subclass B, I am avoiding calling super's (Subclass A) implementation of viewWillAppear:, but I don't think it's correct, even if it works fine.

What is the correct way to still call UIViewController's implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deep class hierarchies often get messy, particularly with `UIViewController`. Avoid them where possible.

One approach is to provide a mechanism for bypassing the functionality provided by a superclass. E.G.:

```
@interface MagicalViewController : UIViewController
-(BOOL)shouldDoMagicOnViewWillAppear;
@end


@implementation MagicalViewController

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   if ([self shouldDoMagicOnViewWillAppear]) {
      //do magic
   }
}


-(BOOL)shouldDoMagicOnViewWillAppear {
    return YES;
}


@end



@interface NotSoMagicalViewController : MagicalViewController
@end

@implementation NotSoMagicalViewController

-(BOOL)shouldDoMagicOnViewWillAppear {
    return NO;
}

@end
```